# Prove $(P\to Q) \lor (Q\to P)$

Tags: logic

Prove that $(P\to Q) \lor (Q\to P)$

In natural language, it reads as: if $P$ then $Q$, or if $Q$ then $P$

Comment: Proof of what? From what?

Comment: (P→Q) v (Q→P), this is a therom frompropositional calculus which I must provide a proof for as part of a logic assignment

Comment: So you want to prove that this is a tautology? I'm sorry I left my mind-reading abilities in my other brain.

Comment: lol, my bad. No do not want to prove it is a tautology using a truth table, instaed was asked to provide a proof

Comment: Either you have to prove this *from* a certain assumption; or you have to prove it from no assumptions, that is, to show it is always true. Propositions which are always true are called *tautologies*.

Comment: Also proofs come with proof systems, inference rules and so on.

Comment: I have to prove it from no assumptions

Comment: i think inference rules are the way forward

Comment: Do you have any particular inference rules? Or just to show, magically or otherwise, that this statement is always true?

Comment: @aaron Are you supposed to use a deductive system or can you just write an argument in english?

Comment: deductive system

Comment: Are you aware of the fact that there are several possible deductive systems? Not all of which are equivalent? As I said, my mind reading abilities are in my other brain, and I don't know which one you have in mind.

Comment: Also, see how hard we need to work in order for you to actually supply us the details to your own problem? Does this sound reasonable?

Comment: Prove what? This is just an expression, not an equation. There is nothing to prove.

Comment: @aaron Have you proved that $\neg (R\rightarrow S)$ is equivalent to $R\wedge \neg S$? Knowing this *might* help making the answer shorter in the sense that we can skip a few steps.

Comment: in regards to natural deduction

Comment: Since all those symbols (at least for some parts of propositional calculus) can typically be defined in terms of their truth tables, a truth table would be sufficient proof for the whole thing.

Answer (score 6):

I think the basic idea is this:
\begin{align}
(P \to Q) \lor (Q \to P) &\equiv (\neg P \lor Q) \lor (\neg Q \lor P) \\
                         &\equiv (\neg P \lor P) \lor (\neg Q \lor Q) \\
                         &\equiv \sf{T} \lor \sf{T} \\
                         &\equiv \sf{T}.
\end{align}
(Sorry about the notation; I hope that it can be understood).

In the first part use the logic indentity (or rule)
\begin{align}
(P \to Q)  &\equiv (\neg P \lor Q)                 
\end{align}
to obtain the right side of the equivalence,
Then is just reordening the terms (beacuse they are all $\lor$)
and finally use :
\begin{align}
(P \lor -P)  &\equiv \sf{T}                 
\end{align}

Comment: Dimitri, I’ve helped you to typeset everything nicely. :)

Comment: Thanks for the editing Haskell, i am not very used to the logic notation in latex

Comment: would you mind explaining this a little please?

Comment: @Dimitri: Not at all! :)

Comment: @aaron did you understand or need a little more explanation?

Comment: I think I need a little more explanation please

Comment: ok, thank you for your help

Answer (score 5):

The comments indicate that a proof using natural deduction is desired, so I'll give some hints about how to do it that way (I won't give a complete formal proof because to be honest I am not very familiar with natural deduction.)

There are only two ways to derive a disjunction that I am aware of: by deriving one of the disjuncts, or by using the law of excluded middle.  Neither of the disjuncts is true in general, so we have to use the law of excluded middle.
This gives us $(P \to Q) \vee \neg(P \to Q)$.  Then we can reduce the problem to deriving $Q \to P$ from $\neg(P \to Q)$.

Assume $\neg(P \to Q)$.  To derive the implication $Q \to P$, we assume the
antecedent $Q$ and derive the consequent $P$. So assume $Q$. Then we can derive the implication $P \to Q$.  But this contradicts our assumption.  From the contradiction we can derive $P$.

Answer (score 3):

$P \to Q$ is false only when P is true and Q is false.
But, in that case
$Q \to P$ is true.
So $(P\to Q) \lor (Q\to P)$ is always true.

Comment: This is exactly the proof one would expect. The result relies on excluded middle (it is not valid in intuitionistic logic) and so we might as well make the use of excluded middle explicit, as here.

Comment: @CarlMummert This proof doesn't necessarily use the law of the excluded middle or even the principle of bivalence.  It could.  But, since it got inferred that P is true and Q is false, it can get inferred that P is true. Since P is true, (Q -> P) is true.  So, ((P -> Q) $\lor$ (Q -> P)).

Comment: Lukasiewicz-Wajsberg 3-valued logic is an example where ((P -> Q) ∨ (Q -> P)) holds and the above rules work.  It's not a theorem in Lukasieicz infinite-valued logic though, and also can take on a value of absolute falsity or '0' in Lukasiewicz infinite-valued logic.

Comment: "when P is true and Q is false."  When someone says a conjunction with the left part true and the right part false, do we judge the statement by the left part making it seem to hold more truth than not, or do we infer the right part and infer the conjunction as false?

Answer (score 3):

Disclaimer: this answer is for fun and to demonstrate yet another method of proving your formula. It assumes basic familiarity with [typed $\lambda$-calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typed_lambda_calculus), so if you don't know what it is, just ignore this post.

---

To prove in classical logic

$$(P \to Q) \lor (Q \to P)$$

we could use double-negation elimination/introduction

$$ \neg \neg P \equiv P$$

and somehow prove
$$ \neg \neg ((P \to \neg \neg Q) \lor (Q \to \neg \neg P)). \tag{1} $$

Let's assume that

$$A \lor B \equiv \mathtt{Left} A \mid \mathtt{Right} B$$

and

$$\neg A \equiv A \to \bot,$$

then the inhabitant of

$$ \Big(\Big((P \to (Q \to \bot) \to \bot) \lor (Q \to (P \to \bot) \to \bot)\Big) \to \bot \Big) \to \bot $$

is

$$\lambda k_0.\ k_0\big( \mathtt{Left}\ \lambda p.\ \lambda k_L.\ k_0 (\mathtt{Right}\ \lambda q.\ \lambda k_R.\ k_R\ p) \big)$$

and this proves $(1)$ by [Curry-Howard isomorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curry%E2%80%93Howard_correspondence).

Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

One way to approach a proof like this is with Boolean Identities. You can find a list of them at [What are a list of helpful boolean identities for solving boolean functions?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/260327/what-are-a-list-of-helpful-boolean-identities-for-solving-boolean-functions/260330). I strongly suggest that you familiarize yourself with these as they prove indispensable for manipulating Boolean expressions.

Answer (score 0):

In Polish notation ((P -> Q) $\lor$ (Q -> P)) corresponds to ACpqCqp.  The system I'll use has the following rules of inference.  The rules are not independent.  I will also use a rule of inference outside the scope of a hypothesis to get discharged or an assumption still in effect, and thus it may get questioned if the following works in the spirit of natural deductive proofs on two counts, though I believe that St. Jaskowski at least would not object to the last two steps:

C-in: From $\alpha$ $\vdash$$\beta$ we may infer C$\alpha$$\beta$ provided that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ have the same scope, and $\alpha$ is a hypothesis.  The right column of the proof analysis will help keep track of which hypotheses are still in effect.

For all the other rules I'll write Q $\vdash$ P where Q is a set of wffs such that each member of Q is under the scope of hypotheses still in effect.

A-in-left: {$\alpha$} $\vdash$ A$\alpha$$\beta$

K-in: {$\alpha$, $\beta$} $\vdash$ K$\alpha$$\beta$

N-in: {C$\alpha$K$\beta$N$\beta$} $\vdash$ N$\alpha$

N-out: {CN$\alpha$K$\beta$N$\beta$} $\vdash$ $\alpha$

K-out left: {K$\alpha$$\beta$} $\vdash$ $\alpha$

A-in-right: {$\alpha$} $\vdash$ A$\beta$$\alpha$

```
                                     Hypotheses still in effect
hypothesis     1 | NACpqCqp                       1
hypothesis     2 || Cpq                           1, 2
A-in left 2    3 || ACpqCqp                       1, 2
K-in 3, 1      4 || KACpqCqpNACpqCqp              1, 2
Ci 2-4         5 | CCpqKACpqCqpNACpqCqp           1, 2
N-in, 5        6 | NCpq                           1
hypothesis     7 || Np                            1, 7
hypothesis     8 ||| p                            1, 7, 8
hypothesis     9 |||| Nq                          1, 7, 8, 9
K-in 8, 7     10 |||| KpNp                        1, 7, 8, 9
C-in 9-10     11 ||| CNqKpNp                      1, 7, 8
N-out 11      12 ||| q                            1, 7, 8
8-12 Ci       13 || Cpq                           1, 7
K-in 13, 6    14 || KCpqNCpq                      1, 7
7-14 Ci       15 | CNpKCpqNCpq                    1
N-out 15      16 | p                              1
hypothesis    17 || q                             1, 17
K-in 16, 17   18 || Kpq                           1, 17
K-out-left 18 19 || p                             1, 17
Ci 17-19      20 | Cqp                            1
hypothesis    21 || Cqp                           1, 21
A-in right    22 || ACpqCqp                       1, 21
K-in 22, 1    23 || KACpqCqpNACpqCqp              1, 21
Ci 21-23      24 | CCqpKACpqCqpNACpqCqp           1
N-in          25 | NCqp                           1
K-in 20, 25   26 | KCqpNCqp                       1
Ci 1-26       27 CNACpqCqpKCqpNCqp                None   
27 N-out      28 ACpqCqp                          None
```